# Как преобразовать время в миллисекунды на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, у меня есть переменная **time = 03:50**, мне надо преобразовать это время (три минуты пятьдесят секунд) в миллисекунды. Чтобы потом использовать в функции window.setTimeout();
Кто может поделиться опытом, как это лучше сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Можно сделать в лоб: минуты умножить на 60000, секунды - на 1000 и сложить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toms(mmss) {
  if(typeof mmss !== 'string') {
    if(mmss.toString) mmss = mmss.toString();
    else throw("Invalid input");
  }

  var parts = mmss.split(':')
    ,n = parts.length
    ,ms = 0
    ,i
  ;

  for(i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    part = parseInt( parts[n - 1 - i]);
    if(i === 0) {
      ms += part * 1000;
    } else if(i === 1) {
      ms += part * 6e4;
    } else if(i === 2) {
      ms += part * 36e5;
    }
  }

  return ms;
}

toms('01:12')    // 72000
toms('01:02:03') // 3723000
toms(55)         // 55000
```

Comment: Этот универсальный шедевр, пожалуй, сохраню) Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let time = "03:50";
    let time_parts = time.split(":");
    let millisecond = time_parts[0] * (60000 * 60)) + (time_parts[1] * 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var split = time.split(":");

var minutes = split[0] * 60000;
var seconds = split[1] * 1000;

var result = minutes + seconds;
```

Такой вариант тоже рабочий. Всем спасибо за ответы.